# doublevalue.ToString() loses decimal places in C#

Tags: c#, c#-4.0

The ToString() of a double value, causes losing of the decimal places

```
(1521.6666666666667).ToString()   ==>  "1521.66666666667"
```

Is there any way to save all the decimal places when converting to string

Also

```
(1521.6666666666667).ToString("F13");   => "1521.6666666666700"
(1521.6666666666667).ToString("0.0000000000000");   => "1521.6666666666700
```

Does this have to do with size of the double value

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to format the string.

`(1521.6666666666667).ToString("R");`

Comment: Yeah this works great, however (1234567890.12345678).ToString("R") will lose the last decimal place, but as for the size of double it will not happen, So with the hope that case will never occur, I will use this ,Thank you

Answer (score 4):

The solution to this is reading the documentation. Seriously It is NOT "ToString" that is loosing it.

Let me quote the float data Type from https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b1e65aza.aspx:

Precision: 7 digits.

The numbers are in your source, they are never in the float. Not properly. The value is rounded.

Answer (score 2):

```
decimal d = 1521.6666666666667M;
d.ToString();
```

According to the [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/364x0z75.aspx):

> Compared to floating-point types, the decimal type has more precision and a smaller range.

Specifically, `decimal` has 28-29 significant digits, rather than 15-16 for `double`.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `Decimal` instead of `Double`:

```
  (1521.6666666666667M).ToString(); // note "M"
```

Another possibility (if you have to use `Double`) is "R" format:

```
 (1521.6666666666667).ToString("R");
```

Answer (score 1):

Use [The Round-trip ("R") Format Specifier](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/standard-numeric-format-strings), which will attempts to ensure that a numeric value that is converted to a string is parsed back into the same numeric value. This format is supported only for the `Single`, `Double`, and `BigInteger` types.

**But** for `Double` and `Single` values, the "R" format specifier in some cases fails to successfully round-trip the original value and also offers relatively poor performance. Instead, we recommend that you use the "G17" format specifier for `Double` values and the "G9" format specifier to successfully round-trip Single values.

From MSDN:

> In some cases, **Double** values formatted with the "R" standard numeric format string do not successfully round-trip if compiled using the `/platform:x64` or `/platform:anycpu` switches and run on 64-bit systems.

Resource: [Standard Numeric Format Strings](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/standard-numeric-format-strings).